# Dúvida quanto a sobrescrita de definições padrões do php.ini

Tags: php

Tenho um arquivo **php.ini** customizado, caso eu omita todas as variáveis que não alterei e mantenha somente as minhas definições customizadas, o PHP irá considerar para as variáveis omitidas o valor default?

Por exemplo, se eu modificar a display_errors e excluir todo o resto, o PHP irá assumir o valor default para as demais?

Comment: Quando você re-iniciar seu servidor ou iniciar vai dar "erro" não vai rodar. Conhecimento empírico  na documentação php.ini só fala que o php quando vai iniciar lê esse arquivo.

https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/configuration.file.php

Comment: Se você tiver um arquivo **php.ini** customizado na pasta do seu projeto, os dados que não forem configurados nele, o PHP, automaticamente, irá buscar os valores no **php.ini** padrão.

Comment: Subi um ambiente de teste e confirmei que, variáveis ausentes no arquivo raiz do php irão assumir o valor default da sua build, ou seja, mesmo que eu chegue no arquivo principal (php.ini) e delete tudo as variáveis essenciais irão assumir um valor default garantindo o start confiável do binário.